# How to upload an image

Tags: support, images

How can I upload an image for a post on this site?

I'm trying to upload an image, but can't find any links to actually do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Click on the image button:

   [image]
2. Paste your image into the dialog:

   [image]
3. Then Confirm your image:

   [image]

You can also pick an image from your computer or enter the URL of an image on the web at step 2.

Comment: Meh, you have more images.

Comment: Needs *at least* two more FHRCs!!

Comment: Well megha's answer is probably not the most constructive way to address the issue, but mentioning the existence of the rep requirement in the answer could make sense.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the image uploader button when you edit or create a post.

[image]

From there you have the option to upload an image from your computer or from the web.